After moving to 24.04, I get "snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0" and "GPU fell off the bus"
After updating to 24.04 LTS "noble", I am now getting a bunch of hardware errors.
Every few minutes, there is the error
"snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible"
I tried the often suggested fix of putting "options snd_hda_intel power_save=0" into /etc/modprobe.d/disablePower.conf, but this did not help.
Looking at the bus, it seems that the device 0000:01:00.1 is actually the audio device of the discrete Nvidia GPU, which sits at 0000:01:00.0. This also has some problems since the upgrade to 24.04:
$ nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

and repeated messages
nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 511
nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none
NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0
NVRM: (PCI ID: 10de:13fa) installed in this system has
NVRM: fallen off the bus and is not responding to commands.
nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 511

The GPU worked under 20.04, so it is likely a kernel/driver issue. Any suggestions?

I found a workaround, but it is a strange one: I blacklisted all nvidia drivers in modprobe.d/ and then load them manually. Then there are no problems, and I can use the GPU for CUDA computing as intended. The snd_hda_intel warnings also go away.

Please post the workaround in your comment as an answer to your own question and you can also click the check symbol beside your answer to mark it as accepted.
